# Как создать и передать в универсальный метод тип созданный по его имени?

Tags: c#, generics, ms-access, рефлексия, datatable

Имеется несколько баз данных MS Access (файлы *.accdb) и в каждой несколько таблиц. В каждой таблице имеются как одинаковые столбцы, так и столбцы, которые имеются только у конкретной таблицы. Для каждой таблицы определён тип со свойствами аналогичными в таблице Access. Стоит задача свести все таблицы в одну таблицу MS SQL. Как решаю задачу на данный момент:

1. Получаю список всех таблиц в БД (файле .accdb)
   `oleDbConnection.GetSchema("Tables")`;
2. Каждое полученное имя таблицы приводится к корректному имени класса/типа;
3. Таблица целиком загружается в [DataTable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netstandard-2.0);
4. "Конвертирую" DataTable в строго типизированный лист по типу определённому на втором шаге;

Универсальный/generic метод расширения для DataTable:

```
namespace RootNs {
    public static class Extensions {
        public static List<T> ToGenericList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new() {
            try {

                var list = new List<T>();
                var columnNames = table.Columns
                    .Cast<DataColumn>()
                    .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                    .ToList();
                var props = (new T()).GetType()
                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable()) {

                    T obj = new T();

                    foreach (string colName in columnNames) {
                        string safeClsName = colName.ToSafeName();
                        PropertyInfo prop = Array.Find(props, x => x.Name.Equals(safeClsName));
                        prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[colName], prop.PropertyType), null);
                    }

                    list.Add(obj);
                }

                return list;
            }
            catch {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу найти решение: каким образом создать и передать в универсальный метод тип созданный по его имени? Может имеется какой-либо другой "безболезненный! способ конвертировать DataTable или таблицы Access в строго типизированный лист?

```
// к примеру, safeClsName = "SimpleClass"
string safeClsName = tableName.ToSafeName();

// Так работает
var test = dataTable.ToGenericList<SimpleClass>();

// Хотелось бы так...
var test = dataTable.ToGenericList<safeClsName>();
```

Comment: [это?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 да! Это как раз то, что искал. Тим, если хочешь, то оформи как ответ, только подгони его под текущий код. Или дай мне знать - я сам себе отвечу :)

Comment: Сам себе ответь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилось с помощью @tym32167 (Тим, ещё раз спасибо!) и следующего кода:

```
// oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

// формат "Полное.Имя.Класса, Имя.Сборки"
var extType = Type.GetType("RootNs.Extensions, RootNs", false);
var dataType = Type.GetType("RootNs.Data.SimpleClass, RootNs.Data", false);

MethodInfo method = extType.GetMethod("ToGenericList");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(dataType);

// Для статического метода первый аргумент null,
// вторым аргументом передаём массив аргументов.
var list = generic.Invoke(null, new object[]{ dataTable});
// теперь list строго типизирован
```

---

#### Ссылки по теме

1. [MethodInfo.Invoke(Object, Object[])](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke?view=netframework-1.1)
2. [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[])](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netframework-3.5)
3. [Type.GetType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netstandard-2.0)
4. [Связанный ответ на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/3129992)